# How is the heartbeat negotiated?

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm trying to determine how the heartbeat is negotiated, if at all. It is, after all, called the "requested" heartbeat. For example, if the server heartbeat is set *lower* than the client heartbeat, the client library should use the *minimum*, right? Otherwise, all connections will be closed by the server.

The [connection documentation](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Connecting-to-RabbitMQ) doesn't really make it clear and I'm not finding much by [searching the code](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=heartbeat&type=) (no conclusive usages of `ConnectionConfiguration.RequestedHeartbeat`).

The server [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-timeout) says

> This value is negotiated between the client and RabbitMQ server at the time of connection. The client must be configured to request heartbeats... (although the client can still veto them).

The "official" [.NET client library](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/c8f415f80741c9becdc4887fa0479c2a1bb6fe61/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/impl/Connection.cs#L1390) uses the minimum of the client or server heartbeat.

```
Math.Min(clientValue, serverValue);
```

Comment: I use golang client library, https://github.com/streadway/amqp,  and its heart beat logic is as follows. 
If any of server or client heartbeat is zero, then max of them is used else min of them is picked.

https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/connection.go#L769

Comment: Trace the connection establishment and handshake with Wireshark. The AMQP protocol analyzer will make it clear what's going on.